# Is it a bad practice to intertwine two classes in c++?

Tags: c++

I give the following examples to illustrate my question:

```
class B;
class A
{
 public:


   class B *pB;

};

class B
{
  public:

     void perform(A &obj)
     {

     }
};
```

In the above two classes. class A has a pointer to class B. class B has a function that will work on class A object. Though it can compile, I was wondering whether this is not a good practice for designing two classes as they are intertwined. If this is bad design, do you have some ideas to avoid it? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is "depends". This is the whole basis for the visitor pattern (you intertwine one class with an entire hierarchy there). But it's not without its problems.

Comment: C++ offers friend classes which even enforces stronger binding then the one that you proposed

Comment: By the looks of the design and although it may compile, here is the one thing to consider. Class A stores a pointer to a Class B object or its memory location. So to construct a Class A object it has to set enough memory aside for a Class B object that it will store. When creating a Class B object it doesn't store any class A however one of its methods accepts a class A object that will do work on it which does store a class B object. There is apparently nothing wrong with this as long as the objects are both complete objects without having any circular dependencies.

Comment: @FrancisCugler `[...]So to construct a Class A object it has to set enough memory aside for a Class B object that it will store[...]`what do you want to say with that? A pointer has always the same size no matter to what data type it points to, it only depends on the platform. When constructed the class could leave `*pB` uninitialized,  set it to `nullptr` or an address passed as parameter to the constructor, class `A `does not need to know any details of `B` for those options. Only if you need to create an new instance of `B`  in the constructor of `A`, then compiler/linker needs to know `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two concrete classes rely directly on one another can get you into trouble.

It is often better to *"program to an interface"*.
There is a long discussion [here](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) under the title "Program to an interface, not an implementation", which draws out why *decoupling* matters

In your example, `void perform(A &obj)` could instead take an abstract base class that `A` derives from. It might be worth having an interface that `A` uses in it's member variable too, but there' no suggested usage in your example to go on.

Why is this "better"? For starters, it will make you think about encapulsation - and what specifically the interface should be exposing.

It will also allow you to use different conrete instantions of the class, say for testing purposes.

If you use an interface, you can change the conrete classes separately... there are many advantages.